# Array order in pytables

Tags: python, numpy, pytables

With [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin)'s [`CArray`](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref.html#carrayclassdescr), is there a way to specify the order in which the data is stored on disk (Fortran/C)?

I am looking for something similar to [`ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)'s `order` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `chunkshape` parameter that in effect specifies the data order:

http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref.html#tables.File.createCArray

For instance, for 2-D data, `chunkshape=(2000, 1)` would be efficient if data is accessed in Fortran order, and `chunkshape=(1, 2000)` if it is accessed in C order. You may need to play with the numbers a bit: http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/optimization.html